# C++ design for CUDA codes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cuda

I have a piece of C++ CUDA code which I have to write declaring the data variable in float. I also have to  rewrite the code declaring the data variable in double.

What is a good design to handle a situation like this in CUDA?

I do not want to have two sets of same code because then in the future for any change I will have to have to change two sets of otherwise identical code. I also want to keep the code clean without too many `#ifdef` to change between float and double within the code.

Can anyone please suggest any good (in terms of maintenance and "easy to read") design?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CUDA supports type templating, and it is without doubt the most efficient way to implement kernel code where you need to handle multiple types in the same code.

As a trivial example, consider a simple BLAS AXPY type kernel:

```
template<typename Real>
__global__ void axpy(const Real *x, Real *y, const int n, const Real a)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;

    for(; tid<n; tid += stride) {
        Real yval = y[tid];
        yval += a * x[tid];
        y[tid] = yval;
    }
}
```

This templated kernel can be instantiated for both double and single precision without loss of generality:

```
template axpy<float>(const float *, float *, const int, const float);
template axpy<double>(const double *, double *, const int, const double);
```

The thrust template library, which ships with all recent versions of the CUDA toolkit, makes extensive use of this facility for implementing type agnostic algorithms.

Comment: wow!! i did not know this existed. thank you very much. is there any tutorial kind of document i can look at.

Comment: There is a brief discussion of C++ features supported in CUDA in the Appendices of the programming guide.

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6179580/681865) for another very useful template based CUDA design pattern.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to templating, you may be able to achieve what you want with a single typedef:

```
typedef float mysize;  // or double
```

Then just use `mysize` throughout where you would use `float` or `double`.

You might be interested in the [simpleTemplates sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#simple-templates), and there are other templatized CUDA examples as well, in addtion to [thrust](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) where, as talonmies states, it's used extensively. Thrust provides many other benefits as well to C++ programmers.

Comment: That can also be a perfectly good option, although it precludes being able to use both versions within the same compilation unit.