# memset cuArray for surface memory

Tags: cuda, cuda-arrays

Say you have a `cuArray` for binding a surface object.

Something of the form:

```
// These are inputs to a function really.
cudaArray* d_cuArrSurf
cudaSurfaceObject_t * surfImage;

const cudaExtent extent = make_cudaExtent(width, height, depth);
cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<float>();
cudaMalloc3DArray(&d_cuArrSurf, &channelDesc, extent);

// Bind to Surface
cudaResourceDesc    surfRes;
memset(&surfRes, 0, sizeof(cudaResourceDesc));
surfRes.resType = cudaResourceTypeArray;
surfRes.res.array.array  = d_cuArrSurf;

cudaCreateSurfaceObject(surfImage, &surfRes);
```

Now, I want to initialize this `cuArray` to zero. Apparently there is non `memset` for `cuArray` type of objects. What would be the best way to do this? Maybe multiple options are possible, and some may have better or worse features. Which are these options?

I can think of

1. allocate and zero host memory and copy it using `cudaMemcpy3D()`.
2. create an initialization kernel and write it with `surf3Dwrite()`

Comment: Note: I plan to now test the two options and report the results as answer. If there is a clear way of doing this, please do answer the question. If you can think of a different way of doing this, please do answer or comment here and I will also test and report.

Comment: another way to do this would be to work in device memory only, allocate device memory, zero device memory, and then do cudaMemcpy3D.  It might be quicker than a host->device copy operation.  I'm not sure what would be quickest.  Hopefully such a thing is not a significant performance issue for your code, in which case I would choose whatever method seems simplest (coding-wise) and easiest to maintain.

Comment: @RobertCrovella ah indeed. Likely the fastest option, but requires double the device memory, which can be an issue in some problems. I will add that one too to my tests though.

Comment: you can free the device memory when you are done with it.  but yes, if you are talking about zeroing a cuda array that is 30GB, this won't work.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Well, yes, I was thinking that for a brief sec there, you need double the memory there. If that cuArray is just a bit half over your RAM, you go over. In the applications I work this is not  an unreasonable to happen.

Comment: You could initialize a large cudaArray from a small buffer by doing multiple cudaMemcpy3D operations (I think).  LoL.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Hum that makes sense indeed ;). I... need to check how to do cudaMemcopy3Ds into different parts of the cuArray though.... Its not the most straightforward API the memory one in CUDA

Comment: @RobertCrovella I have been trying to play with that idea, but honestly I don't seem to get the right way of making the copy.  While I see how `cudaMemcpy3DParms.dstPos` can be used to go copying a small zeroed buffer into the `cuArray`, I don't seem to find a correct configuration of `make_cudaPitchedPtr` to feed into the `cudaMemcpy3D`.... Would it be possible for you to show an example of those lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would it be possible for you to show an example of those lines?

Here is a rough example, roughly extending the [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59886059/1695960) rough example:

```
$ cat t1648.cu
// Includes, system
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>


__device__ float my_common(float *d, int width, unsigned int x, unsigned int y){

// 200 lines of common code...
  return d[y *width +x];
}




////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Kernels
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//! Write to a cuArray using surface writes
//! @param gIData input data in global memory
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
__global__ void WriteKernel(float *gIData, int width, int height,
                                       cudaSurfaceObject_t outputSurface)
{
    // calculate surface coordinates
    unsigned int x = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int y = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    unsigned int z = blockIdx.z*blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;
    // read from global memory and write to cuarray (via surface reference)
    surf3Dwrite(my_common(gIData, width, x, y),
                outputSurface, x*4, y, z, cudaBoundaryModeTrap);
}

__global__ void WriteKernel(float *gIData, int width, int height,
                                       float *out)
{
    // calculate coordinates
    unsigned int x = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int y = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    // read from global memory and write to global memory
    out[y*width+x] = my_common(gIData, width, x, y);
}

__global__ void ReadKernel(float tval, cudaSurfaceObject_t outputSurface)
{
    // calculate surface coordinates
    unsigned int x = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int y = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    unsigned int z = blockIdx.z*blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;;
    // read from global memory and write to cuarray (via surface reference)
    float val;
    surf3Dread(&val,
                outputSurface, x*4, y, z, cudaBoundaryModeTrap);
    if (val != tval) printf("oops\n");
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Program main
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("starting...\n");


    unsigned width = 256;
    unsigned height = 256;
    unsigned depth = 256;
    unsigned int size = depth*width * height * sizeof(float);

    // Allocate device memory for result
    float *dData = NULL;
    cudaMalloc((void **) &dData, size);

    // Allocate array and copy image data
    float *out, *h_out;
    h_out = new float[height*width*depth];
    float tval = 1.0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < height*width*depth; i++) h_out[i] = tval;
    cudaArray* d_cuArrSurf;
    cudaSurfaceObject_t  surfImage;

    const cudaExtent extent = make_cudaExtent(width, height, depth);
    cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<float>();
    cudaMalloc3DArray(&d_cuArrSurf, &channelDesc, extent);

    // Bind to Surface
    cudaResourceDesc    surfRes;
    memset(&surfRes, 0, sizeof(cudaResourceDesc));
    surfRes.resType = cudaResourceTypeArray;
    surfRes.res.array.array  = d_cuArrSurf;

    cudaCreateSurfaceObject(&surfImage, &surfRes);

    cudaMalloc(&out, size);
    cudaMemcpy(out, h_out, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    dim3 dimBlock(8, 8, 8);
    dim3 dimGrid(width / dimBlock.x, height / dimBlock.y, 1);
    // initialize array
    cudaMemcpy3DParms p = {0};
    p.srcPtr = make_cudaPitchedPtr(out, width*sizeof(out[0]), width, height);
    p.srcPos = make_cudaPos(0,0,0);
    p.dstArray = d_cuArrSurf;
    p.dstPos = make_cudaPos(0,0,0);
    p.extent = make_cudaExtent(width, height, 1);
    p.kind   = cudaMemcpyDefault;
    for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++){
      cudaMemcpy3D(&p);
      p.dstPos = make_cudaPos(0,0, i+1);}

    ReadKernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(tval, surfImage);
    WriteKernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(dData, width, height, surfImage);
    WriteKernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(dData, width, height, out);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
$ nvcc -o t1648 t1648.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1648
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
starting...
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

The (total) extent above is  256x256x256.  So I chose to do a 256x256 transfer (per-transfer extent) (basically each z-slice) over 256 iterations of `cudaMemcpy3D`.  It seems to pass the sniff test.

I used 1 as my initializing value for device memory here "just because".  If you wanted to make this faster and initialize to zero, skip the host->device copy and just use cudaMemset to initialize the linear memory (source for 3D transfer) to zero.

Comment: Ah, I am an idiot. I had that exact same code, but I made a mistake on the `p.extent` by reusing the one for `cudaMalloc3DArray`. In any case. I think this is the fastest, and clearer method to do what I asked in the question, while using very little extra memory overheard. Thanks, as usual.